# bindonce with ng-repeat causes errors

Tags: angularjs, bindonce

I'm trying to use `bindonce` with an `ng-repeat` and it is causing the error:

**Controller 'bindonce', required by directive 'ngRepeat', can't be found!**

Here is the div causing the issue:

```
<div bo-if="transcripts.userIsAuthorizedForCourseTranscripts" bindonce ng-repeat="module in transcripts.modules">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Just making sure, but I'm assuming you have included the module as a dependency? `angular.module('app', ['pasvaz.bindonce']);` A jsFiddle that repros the error would be nice...

Comment: Yes I have included it.  I'll have to put together a fiddle to try to reproduce the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have an ng-repeat it actually creates the element from the clone. This means that for everything in the repeat, the new element has both the bo-if and the bindonce. It seems like you want to only do the repeat if you have authority.

So if you want to only do the repeat if `transcripts.userIsAuthorizedForCourseTranscripts === true` then you would nest it like this:

```
// This assumes bindonce is declared above
<div bo-if="transcripts.userIsAuthorizedForCourseTranscripts">
    <div bindonce ng-repeat="i in stuff">
        #This area has bindonce using i
    </div>
</div>
```

I also made a fiddle showing this case http://jsfiddle.net/49c5C/1/

Hope this helped!